# phpMyAdmin and the German Language

Tags: mysql

I am developing a PHP/MySQL application using vertrigoserver. I need to enter the German text in tables. The problem is when I read the tables from PHP, some of character didn't show the exact typed one. Do I need additional steps to display all characters effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set your database fields to `utf8_general` and therefore force your MySQL connection to use [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

```
mysql_connect();
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

While displaying your results through (x)html, you also have to set the headers correctly.

Comment: For storing german texts, the collation latin1_general[_ci] is sufficient. UTF8 adds overhead, that is not always necessary (e.g. it doubles the space needed to store a text)

Comment: For only german texts this is true, Cassy, but imho UTF8 is a more general/international approach.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the correct character set on the tables when you created them?

You should set them to a character set that support ümlaut and such.